# Can't load font with webpack & vuejs

Tags: fonts, webpack, less, vue.js

I have some troubles having my font efficient on vuejs, I have no errors at all, my fonts are in the good folder and my webpack config seems to be efficient.

By the way I use less but I also have the less-loader.

Here's how I do :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'montserrat-extralight';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-family: 'montserrat-light';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/montserrat-Light.ttf');
}
```

And here is where I define the url-loader in my webpack.config :

```
{
  test: /\.(woff|woff2|otf|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
  loader: 'url-loader?importLoaders=1&limit=100000'
}
```

I've found many people with the same problem, but I actualy can't find THE way to make it work.

PS : my font are not uploaded in the network tab within developper mode...

[image: Screenshot of font not being uploaded]

Comment: First of all I don't think a single `@font-face` may specify multiple fonts (should be 1 font per 1 `@font-face`). The way you wrote it the last `font-family` property simply overrides any previous. Though that way you still would have at least one font loaded so this is not the only problem.

Comment: I've done this way a lot of time and didn't have any problem with this syntax !
But as you say this is not the only problem ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finaly found a way to use my customs fonts :

I had the correct syntax but I just had to use .woff or .woff2 font files instead of .ttf or .otf. I can't explain why it's not working anymore, but I got what I wanted so it's allright ~

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems ok, But try to remove **limit** param it may solve your problem, because a font file could very much outsize 100K.

Answer (score -1):

```
new OptimizeCSSPlugin({cssProcessorOptions: {
    safe: true
}}),
```

Comment: Can explain why your solution works in order raise the value of your contribution?